# This is my first time programming and i cant run my code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, g++, syntax-error

Basically when I click run an error pups up

> [Running] cd "c:\Users\alexv\Documents\Playground\" && g++ Hello_World -o c:\Users\alexv\Documents\Playground\Hello_World && "c:\Users\alexv\Documents\Playground\"c:\Users\alexv\Documents\Playground\Hello_World
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:Hello_World: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:Hello_World:1: syntax error
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm using VSC, MinGW and a PC, the program I'm trying to run is a simple hello world:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not an expert in Visual Studio Code however you probably need to show your `json` files.

Comment: `g++ Hello_World`: where is your source file extension (e.g. `.cpp`, `.cxx`, etc.)?

Comment: Related to my first comment: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: I recommended you to use Visual Studio instead of Visual Studio Code. It's much cleaner and easy to use. Also, please don't use `using namespace std;`.[It's considered a bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I would rather recommend eclipse or code blocks, both together with mingw. Admitted, getting the IDE running is a bit of a mess, but once set up, both run nicely. I personally consider especially eclipse as superior to MSVC, more important is a privacy issue: With MSVC, you have to register, so you pay with your personal data, eclipse or CB, in contrast, are *really* free...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the error message is relatively clear.

`g++` accepts several different kinds of files as argument. It tries to determine what kind of file you are handing it by looking at the file name extension.

Your file has no extension, so `g++` defaults to assuming it is a linker script, but it really is a C++ source file.

Use one of the common file extensions for C++ source files and `g++` will handle the file correctly without further options. Common C++ source file name extensions are `.cpp`, `.cc` or `.cxx`.

Comment: Tangential question: who thought that treating unrecognized files as linker scripts was a sensible default?!

Comment: @user253751 Linux executables/scripts, perhaps?

Comment: @user253751 I think it is just directly passed to the linker if unrecognized and since the file is not a valid object file, thats the result.

Comment: I think this is caused by a misconfiguration of visual studio code. Could also possibly be as simple as naming the source file wrongly. Although with that said if the OP has disappeared we may never know.

Comment: Side note: If using no extension (or an unusual one g++ does not recognise), [`-x` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) allows to explicitly specify the language in which to compile the file...